# install quantstrat for R latest R version ()

Tags: r, installation, quantstrat

I would like to install a package when using the latest R version in RStudio.
In particular the quantstrat package
Is that possible?

This is the R latest version I have 3.4.1

my error message:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘quantstrat’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because quantstrat build-fail at R-Forge, you can't get the pre-build file(.tar.gz). You can get the code from github and build by yourself.

```
install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("braverock/blotter") # dependency
install_github("braverock/quantstrat")
```

Comment: This answer is correct.  quantstrat should be installed from github. Note that the R-Forge version explicitly states that the repository has moved to github: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/quantstrat/R/zzz.R?view=markup&revision=1749&root=blotter says "WARNING: this package was installed from R-Forge, but development has moved to GitHub. Please re-install the package using the GitHub repo at: https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat'

Answer (score 7):

Can you provide the installation code that produced that error message?  Are you trying to install it from CRAN?

That doesn't appear possible.

1. A post from 2014 states it's [not on CRAN](http://masterr.org/r/how-to-install-quantstrat/)

   > quantstrat is a R package  ... still under heavy development and can’t be installed from CRAN yet. You can install it from source and the process is straightforward.
2. It's not on the current [list of available CRAN packages](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/available_packages_by_name.html)

It's [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=316) page states the current version 'Failed to build'.

You could download the previous version (and its dependency) from R-Forge  at

- http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/quantstrat_0.9.1739.zip and
- http://download.r-forge.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/blotter_0.9.1741.zip

(or get the Linux tar.gz files).  Assuming they're saved in your personal `Downloads` folder, install it in R with

```
install.packages("~/Downloads/blotter_0.9.1741.zip", repos = NULL)
install.packages("~/Downloads/quantstrat_0.9.1739.zip", repos = NULL)
```

According to that first link, you'll need to install these prereqs first, if they're not already:

```
install.packages("FinancialInstrument")
install.packages("PerformanceAnalytics")
install.packages("foreach")
```

**Edit**: see the comment below from @brian-g-peterson for how the current deployment avenue uses GitHub.  https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly. Very clear answer, thanks

Comment: tar.gz previous versions of quantstrat and blotter are not available at R-Forge for some reason -- does anyone have a solution for Linux?

Comment: I see the links to the linux tar aren't connected.  I guess you should be able to use SVN to download the source files and roll back the clock to a point where the build was successful.

Comment: This GitHub repo apparently is hosted by one of the same guys.  I don't why GitHub & R-Forge  sites aren't connected explicitly.  Check it carefully, and make sure you're comfortable with the risk. you probably want to start a new issue (related to linux & quanstrat) to have a few more people provide their opinions.
 https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat

Comment: note that the R-Forge version explicitly states that the repository has moved to github: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/quantstrat/R/zzz.R?view=markup&revision=1749&root=blotter says "WARNING: this package was installed from R-Forge, but development has moved to GitHub. Please re-install the package using the GitHub repo at: https://github.com/braverock/quantstrat'